# PHP array diff different types

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays of data from different data sources in different formats, but they represent the same resources. So `id` in one is the same as `guid` in the other for example.

Currently I am converting one of the arrays to match the other, and then running them via `array_udiff` to get the difference.

However, I need to compare 3 properties to check if they are a match, so I can't return -1,0,1 as the 3 fields either match, or do not match.

If I simply return -1 or 0, it works comparing `$a` to `$b`, but fails comparing `$b` to `$a`

```
$arr_a = [['id'=>1, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>0],['id'=>2, 'a'=>2, 'b'=>3],['id'=>3, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>0]];
$arr_b = [['id'=>3, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>0],['id'=>4, 'a'=>2, 'b'=>3],['id'=>5, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>0]];

function diff($a, $b) {
   if( ($a['id'] == $b['id']) 
       && ($a['a'] == $b['a']) 
       && ($a['b'] == $b['b']) 
    ) {
     return 0;
   } else {
     return -1;
   }

$not_in_b = array_udiff($arr_a, $arr_b,'diff');
$not_in_a = array_udiff($arr_b, $arr_a,'diff');

print_r($not_in_b);
print_r($not_in_a);
```

The above returns...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 0
        )

)
```

As you can see the diff of `$a` to `$b` works, but `$b` to `$a` does not...

How can I compare multiple vaules like this for equality...

**UPDATE**

This works, but making two arrays with the three identifying properties values as the keys...

```
$arr_a = [['id'=>1, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>0],['id'=>2, 'a'=>2, 'b'=>3],['id'=>3, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>0]];
$arr_b = [['id'=>3, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>0],['id'=>4, 'a'=>2, 'b'=>3],['id'=>5, 'a'=>1, 'b'=>0]];

$arra_a_keys=[];
foreach($arr_a as $item) {
    $arra_a_keys[$item['id'].'_'.$item['a'].'_'.$item['b']] = $item;
}

$arra_b_keys=[];
foreach($arr_b as $item) {
    $arra_b_keys[$item['id'].'_'.$item['a'].'_'.$item['b']] = $item;
}

$not_in_b = array_diff_key($arra_a_keys, $arra_b_keys);
$not_in_a = array_diff_key($arra_b_keys, $arra_a_keys);

print_r($not_in_b);
print_r($not_in_a);
```

Comment: "neither are working".  Show the code you've tried anyway and describe _in what way_ it's not working.

Comment: what items comparing criteria is? only `id` and `guid` should match?

Comment: @PatrickQ I've added an example with some more details...

Comment: added a working example using `array_diff_key`, not sure if there is a better way to do this...

Answer (score 3):

To compare by ids only you can do the following:

```
$ids = array_column($a, 'id');
$guids = array_column($b, 'guid');

$not_in_b = array_filter($a, function ($item) use ($guids) {
    return !in_array($item['id'], $guids);
});
$not_in_a = array_filter($b, function ($item) use ($ids) {
    return !in_array($item['guid'], $ids);
});
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7405e1ebad4c912139856754a7f69516dd4aa32).

Addition:

Also, you can do it with [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php):

```
$compareFunction = function ($a, $b) {
    $id1 = isset($a['id']) ? $a['id'] : $a['guid'];
    $id2 = isset($b['id']) ? $b['id'] : $b['guid'];

    return strcmp($id1, $id2);
};

$not_in_b = array_udiff($a, $b, $compareFunction);
$not_in_a = array_udiff($b, $a, $compareFunction);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aaa46b029e4a919bc0aa44c2051b757cb9985856).

**But be aware [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) is really not the most straight forward function**. There is nothing about this in the documentation, but it not only compares but also sorts the arrays you provided with a callback function. That's why

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

But this sorting also tricks the programmer, because he expected to that in function `int callback ( mixed $a, mixed $b )` `$a` comes from `$array1` and `$b` comes from `$array2`. That is not the case. You can read [this article](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/11/php-arrayudiff.html) to find out more details. So I think that [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) solution is more understandable

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach for make array comparable

```
    $ids1 = [];
    foreach($a  as $v1){
        $i1[] = $v1['id'];
    }
    $ids2 = [];

    foreach($b as $v2){
        $i2[] = $v2['guid'];
    }
    $one_notin_two = array_diff($i1,$i2);
    $two_notin_one = array_diff($i2,$i1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

Here is sample code: [See Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfa2e30f30f23b4baeea9bbb4140e171f2f4f79a)

```
$a = [['id' => 1], ['id' => 2], ['id' => 3], ['id' => 4]];
$b = [['guid' => 3], ['guid' => 4], ['guid' => 6], ['guid' => 7]];

$a = array_column($a, 'id');
$b = array_column($b, 'guid');

$not_in_b = array_diff($a, $b);
$not_in_a = array_diff($b, $a);
```

Hope it should be solved your problem. Thank you.